# Flutter The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error in my flutter app:

**The member 'notifyListeners' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart'.**

I am using this code:

```
void _addButton(LongPressStartDetails details) async {
setState(() {
  animatedIndex = chips.length;
  final chipEntry = ChipEntry(
      offset: transformationController.toScene(details.localPosition));
  marker = chipEntry;
  chips = [marker];
  labelNumber++;
});
await controller.forward(from: 0.0);
animatedIndex = -1;

transformationController.notifyListeners(); //This code gives me the error

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
double encodedX = marker.offset.dx;
double encodedY = marker.offset.dy;
prefs.setDouble('chipx', encodedX);
prefs.setDouble('chipy', encodedY);
}
```

But if I remove the code it doesn't update. And I have tried to use set state instead. But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

[image]

Comment: We need to see more of your code.  Where is transformationController declared and initialized.

Comment: Perhaps you may have forgotten to add  `extends ChangeNotifier` to the class.

Comment: Thank you. I added with ChangeNotifier to the class. And now the error disappears. But now on dispose I get another error."
_FloorPlanWithFixedButtonsState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.

dispose() implementations must always call their superclass dispose() method, to ensure that all the resources used by the widget are fully released.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack."